# setTimeout() dentro de un loop

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Quiero cambiar de color progresivamente las celdas de una tabla, pero siempre deja el ***setTimeout*** para el final,como podría conseguir que no se ejecutase todo el *loop* a la vez.

```js
document.querySelector("#borrar").addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (document.querySelector("#del") != null) {
            for (let td of document.querySelectorAll("#del tr td")) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                  td.style["background-color"] = "white"
                }, 3000);
            }       
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función `setTimeout` tiene más sentido cuando piensas en esta como "Ejecuta esta función cuando haya trascurrido por lo menos x milisegundos **a partir de ahora**".

Tu código espera 3 segundos y ejecuta la primera, revisa si debe ejecutar la siguiente, "- ¿pasaron 3 segundos? - sí" entonces ejecútala, y así sucesivamente. La condición para ejecutar se cumple en todas.

Lo que puedes hacer es variar el tiempo de ejecución, el primero espera 1, el segundo 2 y así.  Un ejemplo:

```js
document.getElementById('cambiar').addEventListener('click', function () {
  let tabla = document.getElementById('del')
  let celdas = Array.from(tabla.querySelectorAll('tr td'));
  
  for (const [i,td] of celdas.entries()) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      td.style["background-color"] = "white"
    }, 300 * i);
  }
});
```

```css
td {
  background-color: black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button id="cambiar">Cambiar</button>
<table id="del">
  <tr><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, creo que he entendido el funcionamiento del setTimeout(), yo creía que cada vez que hacía el loop esperaba 3 segundos.